# Azure Bot Framework V4 (NodeJS) - LUIS recognizer returns error?

Tags: node.js, azure, botframework, chatbot, azure-language-understanding

Using Azure Bot Framework and LUIS.ai to recognize user intent. Performing a get request to the endpoint with the text returns the json object I am expecting, however using the built-in Luis Recognizer I receive the following error: 'Cannot read property 'get' of undefined'.  From the documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-nodejs-tutorial-bf-v4 this appears to be the proper configuration so I am not sure what is going awry.    Any ideas?

```
const { ComponentDialog, DialogSet, DialogTurnStatus, WaterfallDialog, ChoicePrompt, TextPrompt } = require('botbuilder-dialogs');
const { TopLevelDialog, TOP_LEVEL_DIALOG } = require('./topLevelDialog');

const { LuisRecognizer, QnAMaker } = require('botbuilder-ai');
const axios = require('axios');

const MAIN_DIALOG = 'MAIN_DIALOG';
const WATERFALL_DIALOG = 'WATERFALL_DIALOG';
const USER_PROFILE_PROPERTY = 'USER_PROFILE_PROPERTY';
const CHOICE_PROMPT = 'CHOICE_PROMPT';
const TEXT_PROMPT = 'TEXT_PROMPT';


class MainDialog extends ComponentDialog {
    constructor(userState) {
        super(MAIN_DIALOG);
        this.userState = userState;
        this.userProfileAccessor = userState.createProperty(USER_PROFILE_PROPERTY);

        this.addDialog(new TextPrompt(TEXT_PROMPT));
        this.addDialog(new TopLevelDialog());
        this.addDialog(new WaterfallDialog(WATERFALL_DIALOG, [
            this.initialStep.bind(this),
            this.askIfFinishedStep.bind(this),
            this.finalStep.bind(this)
        ]));

        this.initialDialogId = WATERFALL_DIALOG;

        let luisConfig = {
            applicationId: '',
            endpointKey: '',
            endpoint: '',
        };

        this.Luis = new LuisRecognizer(
            luisConfig, 
            {
                includeAllIntents: true,
                log: true,
                staging: false            
            },
            true
            );        

    }

    async run(turnContext, accessor) {
        const dialogSet = new DialogSet(accessor);
        dialogSet.add(this);

        const dialogContext = await dialogSet.createContext(turnContext);
        const results = await dialogContext.continueDialog();
        if (results.status === DialogTurnStatus.empty) {
            await dialogContext.beginDialog(this.id);
        }
    }

    async initialStep(stepContext) {

        let luisAnalysis = await this.Luis.recognize(stepContext);

        let queryString = encodeURIComponent(stepContext.context._activity.text);

        /*
         Ignore this if statement - only in use with the get request 
        */
        if(luisResponse.data.topScoringIntent.intent === 'TrainingExpiry' && luisResponse.data.topScoringIntent.score > .75)
        {
            return await stepContext.beginDialog(TOP_LEVEL_DIALOG);
        }
        else 
        {
            await stepContext.context.sendActivity("I'm sorry, that is not supported at this time or a high enough intent was not acknowledged.");
            await stepContext.context.sendActivity("Top intent: " + luisResponse.data.topScoringIntent.intent + " Score: " + luisResponse.data.topScoringIntent.score);

            return await stepContext.next();
        }        
    }

    async askIfFinishedStep(stepContext) {
        const promptOptions = { prompt: 'Is there anything else I can assist you with?' };

        return await stepContext.prompt(TEXT_PROMPT, promptOptions);
    }

    async finalStep(stepContext) {

        if(stepContext.context._activity.text.toLowerCase() === 'no')
        {
            await stepContext.context.sendActivity("Good bye");

            return await stepContext.endDialog();
        }
        else 
        {
            return await stepContext.beginDialog(MAIN_DIALOG);
        }
    }
}

module.exports.MainDialog = MainDialog;
module.exports.MAIN_DIALOG = MAIN_DIALOG;
```

Note: The issue was in my parameter being passed to the recognizer, as @billoverton pointed out.  The solution is to pass stepContext.context.

Comment: Can you post more details of your error message? If should tell you where you are trying to `get` from an undefined property. Taking a look at that section of code would be helpful too. My initial thought is that there is some issue with your state management. The LUIS configuration itself looks fine.

Comment: @billoverton I have updated the original post with the full error message.

Comment: This appears to be an issue with the stepContext object you are sending to the recognizer. It doesn't contain turnState, and I suspect may not be a turnContext object. Can you log your stepContext object to console and add the results to your question?

Comment: @billoverton Thank you for following up - the issue was in my stepContext object as you pointed out.  Passing stepContext.context instead of stepContext has resolved my issue.  Much appreciated Bill.

Comment: Great! I took my comments and converted to an answer. If it looks good, please accept so that it can help others!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at luisRecognizer.js from the botbuilder-ai module, the error is because the recognizer is expecting a turnContext (with turnState property) and you are sending a stepContext. turnState doesn't exist on stepContext, thus the get property is failing and causing your error. If you send stepContext.context instead, that will fix the issue, i.e. `let luisAnalysis = await this.Luis.recognize(stepContext.context);`

Comment: Much obliged @billoverton